# Scilab create band matrix

Tags: sparse-matrix, scilab

Is there an easy way to make a band matrix in Scilab, something similar to this code for Mathematica:

```
mat=Normal@SparseArray[{Band[{1,1}]->1,Band[{1,4}]->2,Band[{3,1}]->-3},{10,10}];
```

? I know there's `sparse()` function for creating sparse matrices, which I can then transform to normal form via `full()`. But it seems I can only specify single entries for `sparse()`, not bands. Is there something I missed in docs? Or do I have to create it "manually" (i.e. write some procedure for that)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [diag](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.1/en_US/diag.html) function. It creates a matrix that is large enough to contain the values specified. If you combine this with the [linspace](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.1/en_US/linspace.html) function you can create the bands.

### Working example

```
clear;

m = 10;

band1 = sparse(diag( ones(m-1,1),1));
band2 = sparse(diag( linspace(1,4,m-2),2) );
band3 = sparse(diag( linspace(3,1,m-3),-3) );

mat = band1 + band2 + band3;

disp( full(mat) );
```